# port web scraper, scrapy 0.24, to python 3. or use something better

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to use [s**crap**y](http://scrapy.org/) to make a web scraper but I'm running into many problems since it uses Python2. is it possible to run the 2to3 command on all the files in the tarball simultaneously? Would that cause unforseen errors? Is there an alternative web scraper framework which is more up to date, more functional that might be recommended in stead?

I say that because there doesn't seem to be much recent activity on forms on the problems inherent with running version 0.24 of scrapy, i.e. the fact that it's written in python 2.

If scrapy is the best choice, and porting is a bad idea, what's the best way to run this on my python3 oriented machine? a command to run it only with python 2 or something i can change in a config file or whatnot.

**UPDATE**

If you have such problems what you need to do is:

simply run the `setup.py` script with `python2`, i.e.,

```
python2 setup.py install
```

and you're good to go, after that it'll work.

^as indicated by @alecxe

Comment: Are you saying that you are making an attempt to port Scrapy to Python3? The problem is that `Scrapy` is based on  `twisted` and the latter is not there yet.

Comment: yeah, exactly. would that work? is there just a newer more reliable scraper i can use instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with porting `Scrapy` to Python 3 is that `Scrapy` is [built-in on top of](http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/architecture.html#event-driven-networking) the `twisted` event-driven framework, which currently [is not yet there](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/wiki/Plan/Python3).

There is no web-scraping framework as big and mature as `Scrapy` on Python 3. Though, [`pyspider`](https://github.com/binux/pyspider) looks promising, but it is a bit different, see:

- [Can Scrapy be replaced by pyspider?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27243246/can-scrapy-be-replaced-by-pyspider)

Also, there are other libraries related to web-scraping and html-parsing that support Python 3:

- [`beautifulsoup4`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)
- [`lxml`](http://lxml.de/)
- [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/)
- [`MechanicalSoup`](https://github.com/hickford/MechanicalSoup) (built on top of `requests` and `BeautifulSoup`)
- [`selenium`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/)

Comment: so, how could i run scrapy on my machine?

Comment: @flavius_valens well, follow the [installation guide](http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/intro/install.html) or am I missing something? Thanks.

Comment: yeah i did that, but it's giving me all kinds of problems, related to python 3 things, is there a command to run it only with python 2 or something?

Comment: @flavius_valens you need to have Python 2.7 installed and install Scrapy into that Python2.7 environment.