# Having python 2 modules work in python 3 windows

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.x, python-module

So I've been trying to install both Python 2 and 3, but have not had any success. I have tried:
[Multilpe python versions and interpreters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23399867/multilpe-python-versions-and-interpreters)

[How to use multiple versions of Python without uninstallation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10464301/how-to-use-multiple-versions-of-python-without-uninstallation)

I may be doing it wrong. I ultimately want to use modules that only work in Python 2 right now in Python 3, e.g. Scrapy. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it is not possible to use Python 2 libraries with Python 3, since they are not compatible.

Normally, you could use tools like [2to3](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCEQFjAAahUKEwjJ_r-QgszGAhVGlCwKHSLUB_A&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.python.org%2F2%2Flibrary%2F2to3.html&ei=IlidVcnlDMaosgGiqJ-ADw&usg=AFQjCNGsfaZVMPNE7fN2X7QeOm7-m_KWhQ&sig2=wU4SwTFAHHssMkFSMATpdg&bvm=bv.96952980,d.bGg) to make code compatible with Python 3. But Scrapy's dependency `twisted` is also not available for Python 3, see also [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28390386/port-web-scraper-scrapy-0-24-to-python-3-or-scrap-scrapy-for-something-better) and the accepted answer, in which alternatives for Scrapy in Python 3 are listed.

If you really want to use Scrapy, I recommend to use Python 2 in your project.